# How do I copy binaries from a nuget package to my output folder?

Tags: visual-studio, build, package, nuget

I have used Specflow/MSTest to create a test suite.  I need to be able to package this so that a third party can run the tests etc.

I can use vstest.console.exe to execute the features/scenarios using a number of .runsettings I have.

Problem I have is how to copy the files from the Microsoft.TestPlatform nuget package to my project output folder (whether same folder, sibling folder whatever; that is not an issue, I can work that out no worries).  I just can seem to work that out.

I have read a number of posts, on SO and elsewhere, with folk asking same/similar questions but I just cant repro how to do it.

Have tried editing the project file to copy PackageReference 'always', using the 'None' element etc but just can't seem to get it.  Microsoft.TestPlatform is used extensively so I'm guessing that i'm missing something simple here; I just cant get Google to be my friend in this instance.

So, if my .NET5.0 (framework may be irrelevant) project has a Nuget Package referenced but is not referencing it in code anywhere how do I instruct Visual Studio to copy the files from that package to whatever folder I need them to go when I do a build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dotnet publish` is the command you're looking for

> dotnet publish compiles the application, reads through its dependencies specified in the project file, and publishes the resulting set of files to a directory. The output includes the following assets:
>
> Intermediate Language (IL) code in an assembly with a dll extension.
>
> A .deps.json file that includes all of the dependencies of the project.
>
> A .runtimeconfig.json file that specifies the shared runtime that the application expects, as well as other configuration options for the runtime (for example, garbage collection type).
>
> The application's dependencies, which are copied from the NuGet cache into the output folder.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish

Answer (score 1):

Try to modify the package management to "Packages.config", it will auto copy the dlls to output folder.

[image]

If you want to copy dlls to other folder, you can use [xcopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/xcopy) command in post-build event.